# Getting "Invalid column type" exception, while using NamedParameterJDBCTemplate for insertion

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oracle10g, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am using below code while inserting a row into database(oracle 10g xe,jar: ojdbc14.jar)

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO SPONSOR_TB(ID,NAME,INDUSTRY_TYPE,IS_REPORTING_SPONSOR,IS_NOT_SOLICITE) VALUES(SEQ_SPONSOR_ID.NEXTVAL,:NAME1,:INDUSTRY_TYPE,:IS_REPORTING_SPONSOR,:IS_NOT_SOLICITE)";

MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramSource.addValue("NAME1",sponsor.getName());
paramSource.addValue("INDUSTRY_TYPE", sponsor.getIndustryType());
paramSource.addValue("IS_NOT_SOLICITE", sponsor.getNotSoliciteFlag()?'Y':'N');
paramSource.addValue("IS_REPORTING_SPONSOR", sponsor.getReportingFlag()?'Y':'N');
KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramSource, generatedKeyHolder,new String[]{"ID"});
int id = generatedKeyHolder.getKey().intValue();
```

Structure of the table is:

```
create table SPONSOR_TB
(
 id                   INTEGER not null,
 name                 VARCHAR2(20),
 industry_type        INTEGER not null,
 is_reporting_sponsor CHAR(1) not null,
 is_not_solicite      CHAR(1) not null 
)
```

and SEQ_SPONSOR_ID is sequence

And Sponsor class is:

```
public class Sponsor{
      private int id;
      private String name;
      private boolean reportingFlag;
      private boolean notSoliciteFlag;
      private int industryType;
      //getter setter
}
```

And db configuration in spring-servlet.xml is:

```
 <beans:bean
    id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >

    <beans:property
        name="driverClassName"
        value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />

    <beans:property
        name="username"
        value="SPONSOR_DB" />

    <beans:property
        name="password"
        value="ajeet" />

    <beans:property
        name="url"
        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
</beans:bean>
```

I am getting following exception:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/GroupSolution] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO SPONSOR_TB (ID,NAME,INDUSTRY_TYPE,IS_REPORTING_SPONSOR,IS_NOT_SOLICITE) VALUES(SEQ_SPONSOR_ID.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8749)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9471)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9454)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:127)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.setValues(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:581)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:843)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:288)
    at com.groupsolution.dao.SponsorDaoImpl.createSponsor(SponsorDaoImpl.java:55)
    at com.groupsolution.service.SponsorServiceImpl.createSponsor(SponsorServiceImpl.java:31)
    at com.groupsolution.controller.SponsorController.addSponsor(SponsorController.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: By combinig answers from David and Halfbit, got the soultion:

changed my database field from CHAR(1) to CHAR(2)
and then tried

    paramSource.addValue("NAME1",sponsor.getName(),Types.VARCHAR);
    paramSource.addValue("INDUSTRY_TYPE", sponsor.getIndustryType(),Types.INTEGER);
    paramSource.addValue("IS_NOT_SOLICITE", sponsor.getNotSoliciteFlag()?'Y':'N',Types.VARCHAR);
    paramSource.addValue("IS_REPORTING_SPONSOR", sponsor.getReportingFlag()?'Y':'N',Types.VARCHAR);

Thanks to David and Halfbit

Comment: Whenever you see this exp make sure the data you are passing as input are of same type as of the column to which you are passing.
In my case the IN clause I was using was expecting Array of integers i.e [1,2,3,..] but I passed [[1,2,3,...]]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to try using strings instead of characters for your CHAR(1) Y/N fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot @halfbit.. 

changed my database field from CHAR(1) to CHAR(2)
and then tried

paramSource.addValue("NAME1",sponsor.getName(),Types.VARCHAR);
paramSource.addValue("INDUSTRY_TYPE", sponsor.getIndustryType(),Types.INTEGER);
paramSource.addValue("IS_NOT_SOLICITE", sponsor.getNotSoliciteFlag()?'Y':'N',Types.VARCHAR);
paramSource.addValue("IS_REPORTING_SPONSOR", sponsor.getReportingFlag()?'Y':'N',Types.VARCHAR);

It worked for me... :-)

Comment: Whenever you see this exp make sure the data you are passing as input are of same type as of the column to which you are passing. In my case the IN clause I was using was expecting Array of integers i.e [1,2,3,..] but I passed [[1,2,3,...]]

Answer (score 16):

You are getting this exception because you are using `JdbcTemplate` instead of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. `MapSqlParameterSource` works with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you for posting it!

Comment: It's because of variadic arguments in JdbcTemplate.

Comment: FMI Instead of LocalDate you should put`Date.valueOf(localdate)`.

Comment: Whenever you see this exp make sure the data you are passing as input are of same type as of the column to which you are passing. In my case the IN clause I was using was expecting Array of integers i.e [1,2,3,..] but I passed [[1,2,3,...]]

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your code to:

```
paramSource.addValue("NAME1",sponsor.getName(), Types.VARCHAR);
paramSource.addValue("INDUSTRY_TYPE", sponsor.getIndustryType(), Types.INTEGER);
paramSource.addValue("IS_NOT_SOLICITE", sponsor.getNotSoliciteFlag()?'Y':'N', Types.CHAR);
paramSource.addValue("IS_REPORTING_SPONSOR", sponsor.getReportingFlag()?'Y':'N', Types.CHAR);
```

Comment: @David- I tried using Types.xxxx which you suggested. But now I am getting error: SQL state [null]; error code [17132]; Invalid conversion requested;
Even if I changed code to:

paramSource.addValue("NAME1","somename", Types.VARCHAR);
paramSource.addValue("INDUSTRY_TYPE",2, Types.INTEGER);
paramSource.addValue("IS_NOT_SOLICITE",'N', Types.CHAR);
paramSource.addValue("IS_REPORTING_SPONSOR",'N', Types.CHAR);

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was providing an Enumeration datatype instead of a datatype compatible with VARCHAR2 in database (like String ).

My query was like :

```
private static final String QUERY ="SELECT res.id, FROM result res " +
"WHERE res.country = :resCountry ";
```

And at the time of passing the parameter resCountry, I did like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listResult = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(QUERY,Country.US);
```

Now the complaint/exception came from the fact that Country.US was of type **Enumeration Country**

I did the following change to make it work.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listResult = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(QUERY,Country.US.name());
```

After this change it worked fine.

Comment: Whenever you see this exp make sure the data you are passing as input are of same type as of the column to which you are passing. In my case the IN clause I was using was expecting Array of integers i.e [1,2,3,..] but I passed [[1,2,3,...]]

Answer (score 0):

Though it is too late, today I found the same issue. I tried all of the above options which were provided by the other members, but no luck. What I found was, to add a char column in where clause I was providing the java.lang.char in that space.

Suppose my query looks like this - `SELECT * FROM app_config WHERE enable = :enable;`, where the 'enable' column is char(1) column in DB. So while passing the parameter in namedparameterJdbcTemplate, I was passing a java char as `'Y'`, which was causing the error.

In order to solve that I passed normal java string as the parameter value in the namedparameterJdbcTemplate like `"Y"` and BANG!!! It works fine. Also I need not to provide the `Types` in MapSqlParameterSource. So my ultimately code looks like below -

```
protected String getConfigValue(String configKey, String enable) throws BusinessException {
        String value = "";
        try {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(configKey)) {
                MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
                parameters.addValue(ApplicationDaoConstants.CONFIG_KEY, configKey); // This is the VARCHAR column in DB
                parameters.addValue(ApplicationDaoConstants.ENABLE, enable); // This is the character column in DB

                value = nmJdbcTmplt.query(AppConfigSQL.GET_CONFIG_VALUE, parameters, rs -> {
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        return rs.getString(ApplicationDaoConstants.CONFIG_VALUE);
                    }
                    return "";
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception occured while accessing app_config ", e);
            throw new BusinessException(ApplicationConstants.ERROR_ACCESSING_DATABASE);
        }

        return value;
    }
```

I hope this could help others.
Thanks!