# sql error : Invalid conversion requested using Spring JdbcTemplate prepared statement

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am getting the following "Invalid conversion requested" error when tried to insert a row in RECORDERS (oracle 11g) table using spring 3.0.5 JdbcTemplate API.

Any help is much appreciated.

### Error

```
2013-12-03 19:14:40,125,ERROR,,,http-bio-8080-exec-3,RecorderController,Caught exception: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO RECORDERS(RECORDER_ID,RECORDER_NAME,RECORDER_TYPE,RECORDER_IP,RECORDER_URL,ACTIVE_IND)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17132]; Invalid conversion requested; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid conversion requested
```

### Here is our RECORDERS table structure

```
Column          Length  Type        Nullable    Primary Key
RECORDER_ID     3       NUMBER      N           1   
RECORDER_NAME   20      VARCHAR2    N                           
RECORDER_TYPE   1       CHAR(1)     N                           
RECORDER_IP     20      VARCHAR2    N       
RECORDER_URL    100     VARCHAR2    N       
ACTIVE_IND      1       CHAR(1)     N
```

### DAO code:

```
public class RecorderDAOImpl {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static String INSERT_SQL="INSERT INTO RSDVR_RECORDERS"
            + "(RECORDER_ID,RECORDER_NAME,RECORDER_TYPE,RECORDER_IP,RECORDER_URL,"
            + "ACTIVE_IND)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    public void register(Recorder recorder) throws DataAccessException{
        int nextRowNum = this.getNextRowNum();
        char activeInd =this.getActiveIndicator(recorder.getState());
        Object[] objArr = new Object[] {nextRowNum,recorder.getName(),recorder.getType().charAt(0),
                                        recorder.getIP(),recorder.getURL(),activeInd};
        int[] objTypes = new int[]{Types.INTEGER,Types.VARCHAR,Types.CHAR,
                                    Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR,Types.CHAR};

        this.jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_SQL, objArr,objTypes);
    }

    private char getActiveIndicator(final String state){
        LOGGER.info("Enter " + this.getClass().getName() + ".getActiveIndicator()");
        return ("Online".equalsIgnoreCase(state)) ? 'Y': 'N';
    }

    private int getNextRowNum() throws DataAccessException{
        //return next row number
    }

}
```

Comment: The quick and dirty way to troubleshoot this: modify the statement insert only one column and do this for each column and see which one throws the error.  You will have to disable your table constraints.  Another approach: [this poster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069170/getting-invalid-column-type-excecption-while-using-namedparameterjdbctemplate) was successful by using `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR`.

Comment: I followed the solution discussed in poster and worked for me. Thanks for sharing @eebbesen. I am more interested to know why it was failed in the first place using Type.CHAR